# How do i use the ranking function Row_number with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my dummy dataset.

```
ID        Order       Case         Date_created      
123456   25800265        1     2018-06-27 07:40:23 
123456   25800265        1     2018-06-25 05:29:23
123456   25800265        0     2018-07-26 06:16:28
789454   25906588        1     2018-07-12 05:59:50
789454   25906588        0     2018-07-12 07:41:29
789454   25906588        0     2018-07-10 05:43:45
789454   25906588        0     2018-07-09 05:59:26
789454   25906588        0     2018-07-05 10:39:45
287541   32140567        0     2018-07-12 07:41:29
287541   32140567        0     2018-07-10 05:43:45
287541   32140567        0     2018-07-09 05:59:26
287541   32140567        0     2018-07-05 10:39:45
```

I need only one record for each order based on the following conditions.
Return the record where Case=1 when an Order contains both 0 and 1 in 'Case'. If multiple records are present where Case=1 then get the old Date_created record.
If the Order has only Case=0, then return the record with oldest Date_created date.

i.e.

```
ID        Order       Case         Date_created        
123456   25800265        1     2018-06-25 05:29:23
789454   25906588        1     2018-07-12 05:59:50
287541   32140567        0     2018-07-05 10:39:45
```

In Redshift I could accomplish this using the following code.

`select * from
(
select *,
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by Order order by Case desc,Date_created) as latest_time
from tbl
)where latest_time=1`

How do i accomplish this in R?

Comment: group by ID, order by descending Case, then descending date, then select the top one for each ID?

Comment: @RAB Sorry. It is group by order, then descending by Case and ascending by Date_created. I need to do it in the Order level. So I do not need ID here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("123456","123456","123456","789454","789454","789454","789454","789454","287541","287541","287541","287541"),
  Order = c("25800265","25800265","25800265","25906588","25906588","25906588","25906588","25906588","32140567","32140567","32140567","32140567"),
  Case = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  Date_created = c("2018-06-27 07:40:23","2018-06-25 05:29:23","2018-07-26 06:16:28","2018-07-12 05:59:50","2018-07-12 07:41:29","2018-07-10 05:43:45","2018-07-09 05:59:26","2018-07-05 10:39:45","2018-07-12 07:41:29","2018-07-10 05:43:45","2018-07-09 05:59:26","2018-07-05 10:39:45"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date_created = as.POSIXct(Date_created)) %>% 
  group_by(Order) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Case), Date_created) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(row == 1) %>% 
  select(-row) %>% 
  arrange(Order)
```

Comment: Thank you. One of my attempts was similar except that I haven't used two variables in arrange(). Also I think that ungroup() isn't necessary. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's good practice to always ungroup when you're done with group_by...in your specific case it'd do no harm to get rid of the ungroup, but usually you run into hard to debug undesired behaviour if you try to manipulate the same dataset later on.

Comment: Got it. Thank you